# Handsontable not rendering completely on Meteor Template.rendered

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor, handsontable

When I include a handsontable, the column headers dropshadow, column widths, and margins are not initially rendered. When I click inside the handsontable or resize the browser window, the dropshadow appears. In the browser console, if I run `hot.render()` (or `$('#hot').handsontable()` in jquery) everything is re-rendered as it should be.
As a fix, I included a `window.onload`, which works perfectly... but it's hacky. I'd like to understand, why isn't it rendered properly the first time around? Other similar widgets are, so I assume it's a mix of operator error and a handsontable issue. My complete code is below.

```
Template.handsontable.rendered = function () {
  var container = document.getElementById("hot");
  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    startCols: 8,
    colHeaders: true,
  });
  window.onload(= function () {
    hot.render();
  }
};
```